# Join 2 tables based on Date and Quantities

Tags: sql-server, join

```
Table 1:
A  |  B  |  Q1
1    1/1    20
2    1/1    10
1    1/7    30
2    1/21   30
1    1/10   15
2    1/30    5

Table 2: 

A  |  C    | Q2
1    1/10    10    
1    1/12    10
1    1/17    40
2    1/14    10
2    1/23    25
2    1/25     5
```

Q1 is the scheduled quantity and q2 is the delivered quantity. Whenever the scheduled quantity is satisfied by table 2 (after aggregation ), I want that date in table 2 (C) to be associated to the date in table 1 (A). The output is given below :

```
A  | B   |  C  |  Q1  |  Q2
1   1/1   1/12   20     20
1   1/7   1/17   30     30
1   1/21  1/17   15     10
2   1/1   1/14   10     10
2   1/21  1/25   30     30
2   1/30  NULL   5      0
```

So, the critical criteria is the quantities from both the tables matching.

Comment: What happened to 45 on 1/17 in table 2? That became 1/17 - 30 and 1/27 - 15 in the output? How was that calculated?

Comment: There are no built-in aggregates to automatically do this for you.  You will have to use two cursors and a temp table to gather your result set.  You probably should consider caching/saving the result-set so you don't have to run this via cursors every time you query it.

Comment: @JacobH My mistake it should be 1/17 split between 30 for 1/7 and 15 for 1/21

Answer (score 0):

This query needs SQL 2012 or above. You need to change `sum() over (... order by)` with another self join if you are using lower version of SQL. Ideas is to calculate running total for both tables and use it in join condition. You need to find minimal date when running total in second table becomes equal or higher than running total in first table.

```
declare @t1 as table (a int, b varchar(10), q1 int)
declare @t2 as table (a int, c varchar(10), q2 int)
insert into @t1
values (1, '1/1', 20), (2, '1/1', 10)
    , (1, '1/7', 30), (2, '1/21', 30)
    , (1, '1/10', 15), (2, '1/30', 5)

insert into @t2
values (1, '1/10', 10), (1, '1/12', 10)
    , (1, '1/17', 45), (2, '1/14', 10)
    , (2, '1/23', 25), (2, '1/25', 5)

;with cte1 as (
    select 
        *, ss = sum(q1) over (partition by a order by rn)
    from (
        select
            *, rn = row_number() over (partition by a order by cast(substring(b, 3, len(b)) as int))
        from 
            @t1
    ) t
)
, cte2 as (
    select 
        *, ss = sum(q2) over (partition by a order by rn)
    from (
        select
            *, rn = row_number() over (partition by a order by cast(substring(c, 3, len(c)) as int))
        from 
            @t2
    ) t
)
select
    t1.a, t1.b, c = min(t2.c), t1.q1
    , q2 = case when min(t2.ss) is null then 0 else t1.q1 end
from
    cte1 t1
    left join cte2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.ss <= t2.ss
group by t1.a, t1.b, t1.q1, t1.rn, t1.ss
order by t1.a, t1.rn
```

Output:

```
a   b      c      q1    q2
--------------------------
1   1/1    1/12   20    20
1   1/7    1/17   30    30
1   1/10   1/17   15    15
2   1/1    1/14   10    10
2   1/21   1/25   30    30
2   1/30   NULL   5     0
```

EDIT:
Updated only last `select`. Also, you might want to add `rows unbounded preceding` after `order by` in `sum() over (...)` to get better performance

```
select
    t1.a, t1.b, c = min(t2.c), t1.q1
    , q2 = t1.q1 - case when min(t2.ss) is null then  t1.ss - t3.ss else 0 end
from
    cte1 t1
    left join cte2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.ss <= t2.ss
    left join (select a, ss = sum(q2) from @t2 group by a) t3 on t1.a = t3.a
group by t1.a, t1.b, t1.q1, t1.rn, t1.ss, t3.ss
order by t1.a, t1.rn
```

Comment: Hey Uzi what if q1 > q2 but q2 is not 0.

Comment: @TheNoob, provide sample data and expected output for that case

Comment: Made the edit to the question. Minor change in table 2

Comment: `B` and `C` are dates.. month and day, you make a `substring(x, 3, len(x))` what about october?

Comment: That was assumption that B and C are varchars. Substring can be easily changed to get proper values for october. And `row_number` is not needed if columns are dates

Comment: they are varchar, but I think it should be treated as dates. Check your result after edit to input data on `Q2=45->40` column `C` should not be null

Answer (score 0):

Easy task, you need to 'spread' delivered quantity over scheduled quantity.

In order to accomplish this you have to transform schedules and deliveries in single quantity rows and then to 'match' each schedule row on their delivery row.

It works just fine.

I have considered that deliveries can cover schedules with same `A` and with `C>=B`

```
;with
N as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by o.object_id) n from sys.objects o
),
T1 as (
    select *
    from (values
    (1,    '1/01',   20),
    (1,    '1/07',   30),
    (1,    '1/10',   15),
    (2,    '1/01',   10),
    (2,    '1/21',   30),
    (2,    '1/30',    5)
    ) x (A, B, Q1)
),
T2 as (
    select *
    from (values
    (1,    '1/10',    10),
    (1,    '1/12',    10),
    (1,    '1/17',    40),
    (2,    '1/14',    10),
    (2,    '1/23',    25),
    (2,    '1/25',     5)
    ) x (A, C, Q2)
),
t1b as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a order by b, n) x
    from t1
    join N on t1.Q1>=n.n
),
t2b as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a order by c, n) x
    from t2
    join N on t2.Q2>=n.n
),
tx as (
    select t1b.A, B, C, Q1, t1b.n Q2, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1b.A, t1b.B order by t1b.n desc) x, q2 q2x
    from t1b
    inner join t2b on t1b.A = t2b.a and t1b.B <= t2b.C and t1b.x = t2b.x
)
select t1.A, t1.B, C, t1.Q1, isnull(Q2, 0) Q2
from t1 
left join tx on t1.A = tx.A and t1.B = tx.B
where isnull(x,1)=1
order by A, B, C
```

**EDIT 2018-04-04**

This is only the base concept, you should tune it on your system and your data.

Table `N` is only for example pourposes, you need a more performant tally table in your db, I use this (tune it to your qty):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_NUMBERS](
    @MAX INT
)
RETURNS @N TABLE (N INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)  
BEGIN
    WITH
      Pass0 as (select '1' as C union all select '1'),       --2 rows
      Pass1 as (select '1' as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),--4 rows
      Pass2 as (select '1' as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),--16 rows
      Pass3 as (select '1' as C from Pass2 as A, Pass2 as B),--256 rows
      Pass4 as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass3 as A, Pass3 as B)    --65536 rows
      ,Tally as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass4 as A, Pass2 as B, Pass1 as C)  --4194304 rows
      --,Tally as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass4 as A, Pass3 as B)          --16777216 rows
      --,Tally as (select TOP (@MAX) '1' as C from Pass4 as A, Pass4 as B)          --4294836225 rows
    INSERT INTO @N
    SELECT TOP (@MAX) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C) AS N
    FROM Tally
    RETURN
END
```

With tally table you can switch `JOIN` in `t1b` and `t2b` to `CROSS APPLY` to get something like that:

```
;with
t1b as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a order by b, n) x
    from Schedules
    cross apply FN_NUMBERS(Q1) n
),
t2b as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a order by c, n) x
    from Deliveries
    cross apply FN_NUMBERS(Q2) n
),
tx as (
    select t1b.A, B, C, Q1, t1b.n Q2, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1b.A, t1b.B order by t1b.n desc) x, q2 q2x
    from t1b
    inner join t2b on t1b.A = t2b.a and t1b.B <= t2b.C and t1b.x = t2b.x
)
select t1.A, t1.B, C, t1.Q1, isnull(Q2, 0) Q2
from t1 
left join tx on t1.A = tx.A and t1.B = tx.B
where isnull(x,1)=1
order by A, B, C
```

If you have performance issues (normally about MemoryGrant) you can build up a procedure and loop throug schedules and execute this query for each schedule.
It could be much more performant to run this query 6 times with smaller data than 1 time only on the whole data set.

Check to have the right indexes on columns..

But optimization is a different problem.

Have a nice day

Comment: Hi.. This is taking way too long to execute. My tables have millions of records.

Comment: And also producing duplicates

Comment: millions of records are not a problem, there are several ways to get better performances. About duplicates.. maybe it is not clear how you aggregate and associate schedules and deliveries.. give an example of duplicate.